# Creating a Gradient for a customized tabs look

Tags: java, android, xml, tabs, gradient

I would like to create my tabs that look like this.

[image]

but I end up getting an effect like this

[image]

I would like to create a simple gradient on top of the active tab (in this case SEARCH NEAREST) with grey color or something close to white.

Here is the code for Selected

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient 
  android:startColor="#000"
  android:centerColor="#FFF"
  android:endColor="#000"
  android:type="linear"/>
 </shape>
```

How can I go about achieving this effect ? I also want to know how can I achieve rounded corners on both sides. Currently when I choose to the active tab the rounded corners apply only on the right corners. Here is the code for how I am doing it.

as of now I it looks like this.

[image]

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
    android:topRightRadius="7dp"/>
<solid
    android:color="#000" />
<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#fff"/>
```

I want to code in such a way that when I click the left tab the left corners should be activated, and right tab, right corners must be activated.

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

In `<gradient />` you need use `android:angle="90"`. For corners you can create some shapes and change they on click.